# Xam.Plugins.Messaging, Cant Send an attachment

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am banging my head against a brick wall with this.

I'm using XF 3.2, XAM plugin 5.2, sending an email with out an attachment is fine.

I have the following code;

```
    var emailSender = CrossMessaging.Current.EmailMessenger;

    var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()
        .Subject("xyz")
        .Body("redacted")
        .WithAttachment()
        .Build();

    emailSender.SendEmail(email);
```

Now regardless what I try, local PCL path(string, string) , "content//", i can not get anything other than this Error, when sending the email with attachment.

> Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser
>   android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

when I watch the "email", the Java.io.file is null still.

I think I need to use a dependency service to send the email, and then i could use the native file formats, but i would still need to know the full correct path to lets say assets or resources on both platforms.

Comment: There's a note in the README that mentions something about that if you're using API 24 or higher. Take a [look](https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/Messaging/README.md#android-nougat).

Comment: I would suggest you check your manifest for [File Provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) support